# RMSE between all value with same hours with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, calculated-columns

I have two dataframe: the first represents the output of a model simulation and the second the real value. I would like to compute the RMSE between all the value with the same hours. Basically I should compute 24 RMSE value, one for each hour.

These are the first columns of my dataframes:

```
date;model
2017-01-01 00:00:00;53
2017-01-01 01:00:00;52
2017-01-01 02:00:00;51
2017-01-01 03:00:00;47.27
2017-01-01 04:00:00;45.49
2017-01-01 05:00:00;45.69
2017-01-01 06:00:00;48.07
2017-01-01 07:00:00;45.67
2017-01-01 08:00:00;45.48
2017-01-01 09:00:00;42.06
2017-01-01 10:00:00;46.86
2017-01-01 11:00:00;48.02
2017-01-01 12:00:00;49.57
2017-01-01 13:00:00;48.69
2017-01-01 14:00:00;46.91
2017-01-01 15:00:00;49.43
2017-01-01 16:00:00;50.45
2017-01-01 17:00:00;53.3
2017-01-01 18:00:00;59.07
2017-01-01 19:00:00;61.71
2017-01-01 20:00:00;56.26
2017-01-01 21:00:00;55
2017-01-01 22:00:00;54
2017-01-01 23:00:00;52
2017-01-02 00:00:00;53
```

and

```
date;real
2017-01-01 00:00:00;55
2017-01-01 01:00:00;55
2017-01-01 02:00:00;55
2017-01-01 03:00:00;48.27
2017-01-01 04:00:00;48.49
2017-01-01 05:00:00;48.69
2017-01-01 06:00:00;49.07
2017-01-01 07:00:00;49.67
2017-01-01 08:00:00;49.48
2017-01-01 09:00:00;50.06
2017-01-01 10:00:00;50.86
2017-01-01 11:00:00;50.02
2017-01-01 12:00:00;33.57
2017-01-01 13:00:00;33.69
2017-01-01 14:00:00;33.91
2017-01-01 15:00:00;33.43
2017-01-01 16:00:00;33.45
2017-01-01 17:00:00;33.3
2017-01-01 18:00:00;33.07
2017-01-01 19:00:00;33.71
2017-01-01 20:00:00;33.26
2017-01-01 21:00:00;33
2017-01-01 22:00:00;33
2017-01-01 23:00:00;33
2017-01-02 00:00:00;33
```

due to the fact that I am considering one year, I have to consider 365 value for each RMSE computation.

Up to now, I able only to read the dataframes. One option could be to set-up a cycle between 1-24 and to try do create 24 new dataframes by means of dfr[dfr.index.hour == i-th hours].

Do you have some more elegant and efficient solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMSE depends on the pairing order so you should join the `model` to the `real` data first, then group by hour and calculate your RMSE:

```py
def rmse(group):
    if len(group) == 0:
        return np.nan
    
    s = (group['model'] - group['real']).pow(2).sum()
    return np.sqrt(s / len(group))
    
result = (
    df1.merge(df2, on='date')
        .assign(hour=lambda x: x['date'].dt.hour)
        .groupby('hour')
        .apply(rmse)
)
```

Result:

```
hour
0     14.21267
1      3.00000
2      4.00000
3      1.00000
4      3.00000
5      3.00000
6      1.00000
7      4.00000
8      4.00000
9      8.00000
10     4.00000
11     2.00000
12    16.00000
13    15.00000
14    13.00000
15    16.00000
16    17.00000
17    20.00000
18    26.00000
19    28.00000
20    23.00000
21    22.00000
22    21.00000
23    19.00000
dtype: float64
```

---

## Explanation

Here what the code does:

- `merge`: combine the two data frames together based on the `date` index
- `assign`: create a new column `hour`, extracted from the `date` index
- `groupby`: group rows based on their `hour` values

`apply` allows you to write a custom aggregator. All the rows with `hour = 0` will be sent into the `rmse` function (our custom function), all the rows with `hour = 1` will be sent next. As an illustration:

```
date                 hour  model  real
2017-01-01 00:00:00  0     ...    ...
2017-01-02 00:00:00  0     ...    ...
2017-01-03 00:00:00  0     ...    ...
2017-01-04 00:00:00  0     ...    ...
--------------------------------------
2017-01-01 01:00:00  1     ...    ...
2017-01-02 01:00:00  1     ...    ...
2017-01-03 01:00:00  1     ...    ...
2017-01-04 01:00:00  1     ...    ...
--------------------------------------
2017-01-01 02:00:00  2     ...    ...
2017-01-02 02:00:00  2     ...    ...
2017-01-03 02:00:00  2     ...    ...
2017-01-04 02:00:00  2     ...    ...
--------------------------------------
2017-01-01 03:00:00  3     ...    ...
2017-01-02 03:00:00  3     ...    ...
2017-01-03 03:00:00  3     ...    ...
2017-01-04 03:00:00  3     ...    ...
```

Each chunk is then sent to our custom function: `rmse(group=<a chunk>)`. Within the function, we reduce that chunk down into a single number: its RMSE. That's how you get the 24 RMSE numbers back as a result.

Comment: Actually, in my case 'date' is an index. This is due to the fact that I have read the data with "parse_dates=True" .  Is there any alternative respect to read with "parse_dates=False"?

Comment: If `date` is the index, simply change the lambda to: `lambda x: x.index.hour`

Comment: Thanks. I am really sorry but you code illustrates very advance pandas features. It's ok. I am learning a lot. I have split you code in parts in order to understand. "assign" add a column based in hour in the index. "groupby" create an object, which is not printable with "print". This is what I do:
aa = df.assign(hour=lambda x: x.index.hour)
aa = aa.groupby('hour')
s = (aa['model'] - aa['real']).pow(2).sum().
However, I get the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'SeriesGroupBy'. 
Could you please help me once more?

Comment: My apology for not explaining the code. See my edited answer above. `aa['model']` does not work because `aa` is not a DataFrame, it's a SeriesGroupBy object. `aa.apply(...)` will divide the frame into chunks based on the `groupby` column and send each chunk into our custom function

Comment: Don't worry. You have helped me a lot. If I can, I would like to ask you one more questions just to loeran more. If I understand correctly, ".apply" is a method specific for "SeriesGroupBy" object. How can it know that it works with "hour" and not another column\things. It this related to the fact that we have used "groupby" with "hour"?

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. When you call `groupby`, you dividing the DataFrame into chunks according to the value in that column (`hour` in our case). Then you apply an aggregator (min, max, sum, etc.) on each chunk. In our case, we created our own aggregator and called `apply` to execute it

Comment: I would have another question in case the dataframes has multiple columns. Shall I ask here or open another treat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227085/discussion-between-code-different-and-diedro).

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide to `by=` a function that takes the date and extract the hour.

```
import pandas as pd
from time import strptime

df = pd.DataFrame([
['2017-01-01 00:00:00', 53],
['2017-01-01 01:00:00', 52],
['2017-01-02 00:00:00', 53],
['2017-01-03 01:00:00', 50],
['2017-01-04 00:00:00', 53]
], columns=['date', 'model'])

def group_fun(ix):
    return strptime(df['date'][ix], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tm_hour

print(df.groupby(by=group_fun).std())

   model
0  0.000000
1  1.414214
```